# problem with parametrized circuits

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, ibm-q-experience, quantum-circuit, ibm-quantum-devices

I used a circuit with one parametrized gate U(theta, phi, lambda), than I fixed the parameters with qc.bind_parameters and it's worked well. But the only step that don't work is the execution in a device (real and simulator) and a get the following error output:

'Mismatch between run_config.parameter_binds and all circuit parameters. Parameter binds: [] Circuit parameters: [ParameterView([Parameter(lamb), Parameter(phi), Parameter(theta)])]'

Answer (score 2):

Actually `bind_parameters()` didn't work properly. You can easily see that by noticing that the parameter names appear in the circuit plot. For bound parameters, parameter values are shown in the circuit plot instead of parameter names.

This issue is caused by the controlled-U gate. For details see here: https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/pull/9118.

As a workaround, you can transpile the circuit before calling `bind_parameters()`:

```
qc1 = transpile(qc1, basis_gates=['cx', 'u'])
qc = qc1.bind_parameters(variables)
```

Comment: The problem is when running the circuit:

Comment: I updated my answer based on the extra details you provided

Comment: Thank you for the help!